# gameObject activates without collision. How to disable gameObject activation on scene start?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to activate gameObjects based on the camera as collider and a collider on the trigger. This is the simple script i’ve written for that. It works great but the gameObjects by default are activated and I have to deactivate them by doing an entry/exit once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class reveal : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject Stand;

/// <summary>
/// OnTriggerEnter is called when the Collider other enters the trigger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="other">The other Collider involved in this collision.</param>
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Stand.SetActive(true);
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Stand.SetActive(false);
}


}
```

To fix this I modified the script to deactivate the gameObject before the scene starts and here the issue is that the trigger/ collider interaction no longer works. I think the piece of code I’ve added just deactivated the objects for good.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class reveal : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Stand;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Stand = GameObject.Find("Stand");
    Stand.gameObject.SetActive(false);

}

//public GameObject Confrontation;

/// <summary>
/// OnTriggerEnter is called when the Collider other enters the trigger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="other">The other Collider involved in this collision.</param>
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Stand.SetActive(true);
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    Stand.SetActive(false);
}
}
```

What’s the right way to implement this?? Any ideas?

Comment: Note that if you attach your script to the GameObject, it won't be active again if you try calling `SetActive();`

Comment: I have attached the script to a separate trigger Object which the collider interacts with.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to still use your script you can create another empty game object and adding the script that that object instead of directly on the object which you are disabling.

I'm not sure I totally understand your question if you just want the game object hidden so you can't see it but still being able to interact with the collider. you could instead do this

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Stand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
    }
    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Stand.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;   
}

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and for that script, CubeCrafter360. I have a trigger object that the script is attached to which the collider interacts with and controls the activation of the object Stand if that makes sense. Camera/ player has the collider. Hope that's clear.

Comment: What you are suggesting is an alternative to the SetActive(true/false) is my guess.  My main problem is that when the scene starts, without any interaction, the gameObjects are already activated even though I've turned them off by default.